# How to read Firebase child value?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I'm a newbie to coding and Swift.
I'm trying to retrieve the value of house1Colour from my Firebase database in my app. I've tried these methods so far.

```
let eg = FIRDatabase.database().reference(withPath: "test")
```

(when I use this I get a THREAD 1 Signal SIGABRT error, I'm not sure why)

and:

```
var test:String!

FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("house1Colour").observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snap) in
    if let snapDict = snap.value as? Dictionary <String, AnyObject>{
        self.test = snapDict["house1Colour"] as! String

        print(self.test)
    }
})
```

None of them work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of `FIRDatabase.database().reference().child("house1Colour")` is just the string since you already specified the key `house1Colour`.

Therefore you should be able to just:

```
if let snapString = snap.value as? String {
    print(snapString)
}
```